# GROUP_CONCAT gives incorrect values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have 3 tables: Users, Properties, Units

User table:

```
user_id   user_name
```

Properties table

```
pty_id   pty_name   user   pty_status
```

Units Table

```
unit_id   unit_name  pty_id  unit_status
```

i want to show user details , number of properties and units and their details.
Here is my query:

```
   DB::statement('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10485760');

      $ar = DB::table('users as u')
         ->leftjoin('properties as p', function($join)  {
                   $join->on('p.user_id', '=', 'u.user_id')->where('p.pty_status', '!=' ,0 ); 
                  })

         ->leftJoin(
                 DB::raw("
                  (select COALESCE(count(unit_id),0) AS cntunits, pty_id as temp_pty
                  from  property_units as pu3 
                  left join properties as p2 on pu3.unit_pty_id = p2.pty_id
                  where pu3.unit_status!=0  
                  group by p2.pty_id) as temp"), 'p.pty_id', '=', 'temp.temp_pty')

          ->select(
      DB::raw("group_concat(DISTINCT CONCAT(ej_p.pty_id,'|',ej_p.pty_name,'|',cntunits)) as pty_details"), 
      DB::raw("group_concat(DISTINCT CONCAT(ej_p.pty_id,'|',ej_p.pty_name)) as pty_details_copy")
    )->paginate(10);
```

When I group_concat the unit_count, only those properties and units are concated where unit exists.

For example the above query returns the following result:

```
 pty_details              pty_details_copy
  7|I2|2       7|I2, 22|tR ,51|SG APARTMENT,54_||_GA APARTMENTS,
```

Why properties with units (where unit count=0) are not binding? Where have I gone wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is the raw query:

```
select group_concat(DISTINCT CONCAT(p.pty_id,'|',p.pty_name,'|',cntunits)) as pty_details, 
     group_concat(DISTINCT CONCAT(p.pty_id,'|',p.pty_name)) as pty_details_copy
     from users as  u
     left join properties as p on p.user_id = u.user_id and p.pty_status !=0
     left join 
     (select COALESCE(count(unit_id),0) AS cntunits, pty_id as temp_pty
                  from  property_units as pu3 
                  left join properties as p2 on pu3.unit_pty_id = p2.pty_id
                  where pu3.unit_status!=0  
                  group by p2.pty_id) as temp on p.pty_id = temp.temp_pty
```

Comment: group_concat, has a max limit, usually it's much more then what you have but just saying.

Comment: max_length? I have changed the default by :       DB::statement('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10485760');

Comment: Query builders are such junk, your query is too chopped up for me to really look at it, sorry, the limit is just my go to on these types of questions. I would suggest trying the query in Mysql, through PHPmyadmin, first tell you get what you want.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I have updated it with my sql raw query

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your expected outcome or the data is, but does adding `coalesce` in `... p.pty_name,'|',coalesce(cntunits,0)) as pty_details, ...` helps? I assume that the `coalesce` in your left join might not do what you think it does.

Comment: AS I mentioned I would try the query first in PHPmyadmin, this eliminates any code issues, I would also try the inner query separately to make sure it returns what you think it should.   When queries get this complex it can help to provide a DB fiddle with some data and the query in it to help debug, it's exceedingly difficult to run this in your head with limited information.

Comment: @Solarflare Thank you.  Its working fine with this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Solarflare suggested, i got the required result when I changed the query like this:

```
  $ar = DB::table('users as u')
     ->leftjoin('properties as p', function($join)  {
               $join->on('p.user_id', '=', 'u.user_id')->where('p.pty_status', '!=' ,0 ); 
              })

     ->leftJoin(
             DB::raw("
              (select COALESCE(count(unit_id),0) AS cntunits, pty_id as temp_pty
              from  property_units as pu3 
              left join properties as p2 on pu3.unit_pty_id = p2.pty_id
              where pu3.unit_status!=0  
              group by p2.pty_id) as temp"), 'p.pty_id', '=', 'temp.temp_pty')

      ->select(
  DB::raw("group_concat(DISTINCT CONCAT(ej_p.pty_id,'|',ej_p.pty_name,'|',coalesce(cntunits, 0))) as pty_details"))->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE from your first join should be part of the ON.

Comment: it is currently the part of join.